# how to make find() function using vector (class)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, find, std

there is class like as

```
class C_Service
{
public :

    C_Service(); {memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));}
    C_Service(int type, int idx) {memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));   this->type = type;  this->idx = idx;}
    bool operator==(const C_Service& svc) const { return (this->type == svc.type && this->idx == svc.idx);}

    word    type;
    word    idx;

    dword   aId;
    dword   bId;
    char*   name; 
};
```

I used test code as below,

```
void vec_find(int type, int idx)
{
    vector<C_Service*> vec;

    // added several items in vector vec
    ...

    vector<C_Service*>::iterator iter;
    C_Service cSvc(type, idx);
    iter = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &cSvc);
    C_Service* findsvc = *iter;
    if(findsvc)
        printf("FOUND : type(%d), idx(%d), name(%s)\n", findsvc->type, findsvc->idx, findsvc->name);
    else
        printf("Not FOUND!!\n");
}
```

then, it give "Not FOUND!!" even set correct value.
I found something wrong and trying change..

```
iter = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &cSvc);
```

to

```
iter = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cSvc);
```

remove `"&"`
then it give compile error message

> /libcxx/algorithm: In instantiation of '_InputIterator
>   std::__1::find(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Tp&) [with
>   _InputIterator = std::__1::__wrap_iter; _Tp = C_Service]':
>
> no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'C_Service*' and 'const
>   C_Service')

I searched that when I use `find()` function in Container, It can use `operator==`
but, I can't get a goal..T.T

What is my fault?

Comment: What is the type of `vec`?

Comment: vector<C_Service*> vec;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `vec` is a vector of pointers, not a vector of `C_Service` objects.

Thus

```
find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), &cSvc)
```

checks whether the address of the `cSvc` variable is contained within `vec` (which it's not because you just created `cSvc` so it can't be referenced from anywhere else). It does not use your `operator==` at all, it just compares pointers.

To fix it, you can either change `vec` to be a `std::vector<C_Service>` and do

```
find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cSvc)
```

or pass a custom predicate to `find_if`, where you can dereference your pointers manually:

```
find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const C_Service *p) { return *p == cSvc; })
```

Comment: Well, you are simply faster than me :)

Comment: @AndyLee consider accepting this answer if it has solved your problem.